# Can't remove the user id from upvotes section

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've tried almost everything splice, pop, shift, remove but I can't remove the user id which simple means downvote the post.

Here is my code:

```
// @type    POST
// @route   /api/question/upvote/:id
// @desc    route for upvoting answers to questions
// @access  PRIVATE

router.post('/upvote/:id', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res)=> {
    Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
        .then(profile => {
            Question.findById(req.params.id)
                .then(question => {
                    if(question.upvotes.filter(upvote => upvote.user.toString() === req.user.id.toString()).length > 0){
                        return res.status(400).json({noUpvote : 'User is downvoted the question'});
                    }
                    question.upvotes.unshift({user : req.user.id});
                    question.save()
                        .then(question => res.json(question))
                        .catch(err => console.log('Error on saving the upvote user id :' + err));
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('Error on getting the question : ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error on finding the user : ' + err));
});
```

There are the three models in my application:

```
//Load the Person Model
const Person = require('../../models/Person');

//Load the Profile Model
const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');

//Load the Questions Model
const Question = require('../../models/Questions');
```

So the upvote is in question model.
The `Person` model contains the registration and login information.
The `Profile` model contains the Person details. The `Question` model contains question, answer, comment, and upvotes.

Here is the question model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const QuestionSchema = new Schema({

    user : {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'myPerson'
    },
    textone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    texttwo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    upvotes: [{
        user : {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'myPerson'
        }
    }],
    answers:[{
        user : {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'myPerson'
        },
        answer: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        name:{
            type: String
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }
    }],
    comments: [{
        user : {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'myPerson'
        },
        name:{
            type: String
        },
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        }

    }],
    date: {
        type:Date,
        default: Date.now
    }


});

module.exports = Questions = mongoose.model("myQuestion", QuestionSchema);
```

Comment: Could you show the question Model ?

Comment: Yes i m adding it @Toothgip

Comment: Added @Toothgip plz check it

Comment: Maybe it will more relevant to use an update instead of a findById or there is a reason?

Comment: Actually this entire application is learning videos i m trying to different thing doing the downvote @Toothgip

Comment: What is the purpose of the condition at the beginning? and where's your code that's supposed to remove the id?

Comment: the code is in above. In this code i will take the question id then check the user login and then check that the particular user logged in is upvoted the question or not if not the upvote. I want to do some additional thing if the user upvoted again check it will downvote

Comment: @NarayanMaity You forgot an id in you filter condition. You have `upvote.user.toString() === req.user.id.toString()).length > 0`  instead of `upvote.user.id.toString() === req.user.id.toString()).length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the id using filter.

```
question.upvotes = question.upvotes.filter(upvote => upvote.user.toString() !== req.user.id.toString());
question.save();
```

add it inside the if condition if this is where you want to remove it.